# Docker Global Mode Greater Than 1

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I know this might be an esoteric use-case, but I was wondering if you can specify that you want a docker service to run the same container twice (or X times) on each node.

It's not replicated mode because there's not a fixed number, it depends on the number of nodes.  As far as I know, however, global doesn't support specifying a replication factor per node.

Answer (score 0):

There's no feature as you're specifically asking, I would just add X Services in global mode and use a proxy in front of them (without knowing anything else about your setup).

Maybe you should ask more specific about your solution requirements and then maybe a more creative solution can be suggested.